# Update Xperia Mini Pro (SK17i) to Jelly Bean

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean, sony-xperia-mini-pro

How can I update my [Xperia Mini Pro (SK17i)](http://www.sonymobile.com/in/products/phones/xperia-mini-pro/) to [Jelly Bean (Android 4.2)](http://www.android.com/whatsnew/)? Please provide me the best step by step guide.

Comment: Would this be of any [help](http://talk.sonymobile.com/thread/97327)?

Comment: Does Xperia Mini pro (SK17i) has an official update beyond 4.0?

Comment: @t0mm13b: Is this unrootable?

Comment: @Narayanan: My device is showing Android version 4.0.4. Probably this is the latest released by Sony for my mobile.

Comment: I had understood your question as "How do I root my Xperia Mini Pro (SK17i) running Jellybean?" and hence was surprised to know that JB update was not available officially by Sony. If so, then you should be on custom ROM which means you would be rooted - most likely. With your info that yours is running 4.0.4, I presume you are asking "How to update my Xperia Mini Pro (SK17i) to Jellybean?". Pl. confirm.

Comment: @Narayanan: Android 4.0.4 is not Jelly Bean. Its [ICS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.0.3.E2.80.934.0.4_Ice_Cream_Sandwich_.28API_level_15.29). And I have never installed any custor ROM in my device. This update is provided to me by Sony.

Comment: Looking at the comments, I very much assume that what the OP wants to really do is upgrade his device to the latest version of Android (then 4.2).