# How to root Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini Pro with linux computer

Tags: rooting, linux, sony-xperia-mini-pro

I have found a lot instructions, but most (or all) of them use a Windows GUI application to root the device. The Linux scripts, that I found did not work.

My telephone:

- Model: Xperia Mini Pro (SK17i)
- Android-Version: 4.0.4
- Kernel-Version: 2.6.32.9-perf
- Build-Nummer: 4.1.B.0.587

How can I root this phone with a linux computer?

**HINT**
This is not a duplicate question, because I want to do it from Linux (not Windows) and second the [alleged solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) does not contain an answer for my phone!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) - Once you look at that, take a look at [Update Xperia Mini Pro (SK17i) to Jelly Bean](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41568/update-xperia-mini-pro-sk17i-to-jelly-bean)

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate, because the linked answer does not contain a possibility for this phone (although linked to another answer, but which has no solution!).

Comment: I've just updated the main rooting answer to point to this question as the previously linked 'answer' for this phone was not actually about rooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with Wine and the windows variant of this: [cydiaimpactor.com](http://cydiaimpactor.com) using this instructions from here: [forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2399464](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2399464)

Answer (score 1):

install **wine on linux**, then run windows program and root
**[download link](https://www.winehq.org/download/) :**

> or install windows on vmware.

Comment: It worked, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could install CyanogenMod on it, [their instructions](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_mango) have worked out on Linux for me.